# Visual Studio 2012 - How to Create Resource-Only DLL

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm looking for a quick overview on how to create a resource-only DLL in Visual Studio 2012. I found this old article for Visual Studio 2005, but that doesn't exactly appear to be relevant anymore:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/24b2tcy0(v=VS.80).aspx

The goal is that I (the graphics guy, not the programmer) can make the resources DLL for the programmer to pull bitmaps and icons from. I can follow instructions, and have enough Visual Studio experience to figure out at least cursory instructions - I'm just looking for a starting point if nothing else.

Thanks in advance,
Beems

Comment: Is this for a Managed project? In that case you can simply create an empty C# Class Library and add your resources to that. Adding a tag for your platform/language will probably help us give you a better answer.

Comment: The developers of the primary application use C#, but I don't know that it matters to me which language is used for the DLL, so long as they can reference the DLL to pull images from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Start a new project of "class library" type.
- There will be a single class, depending on the language you chose it
  will be named differently. Delete it.
- Add your resources to the project, change their properties to
  "Embedded Resource"
- Compile

Comment: Language: C#
Sten, thanks, that is close to what I need. However, if I open the DLL in an application like Resource Hacker, I don't see the images. Is there something else I have to do to make that work?

Comment: I haven't used Resource Hacker but this approach has worked for me in the past, not sure what's going on

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty sure we're on the right track anyway. I'll post another question on how to ensure that when I compile the DLL that I'm able to see the individual resources when opened in an application like Resource Hacker.

Comment: @Beems, I think resource-only DLLs created by C++ and C# are different.